# Dipole antenna director

Tags: antenna, reflection, dipole

Say a free metal rod is placed at a distance λ/2 from a dipole antenna (fig), both being of same length. I understand it will reflect and dampen the signal going to the left. But how will it impact the signal going to the right in comparison to no rod? And how will its length impact that result?

EDIT: 
I meant this to be a transmitting antenna, but it would probably work both ways. The reason for the question is it was a theoretical question with a explanation I did not agree with. As in comments I agree there will be a dampening due to reflection, and also a possible narrowing or widening of the radiation pattern (with changed lobe-maxima). If a length longer than the dipole reflects and a shorter directs, then I assume that would mean the ratio of the effect of reflection/direction. As I can only imagine it will always reflect to some degree, and always direct to some degree, either by widening or narrowing the lobe(s)...(?)

[image]

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the signal to the left will be greater by the same amount (minus losses) that the right signal is weaker.  That is (as I read it) the opposite of your expectation.

Comment: I have seen two way radio antennas mounted with the dipole a specific distance from the mast to make a directional antenna.  The direction is from the mast to through the dipole, to the area you want to receive from or transmit to.

Comment: Where is the transmit signal coming from?

Comment: An element (or elements) longer than the radiator will reflect; an element (or elements) shorter than the radiator will direct. The ratio of lengths between the radiator(s) (i.e. driven elements) and parasitic elements is normally quite small, but log periodic arrays, for example, may have progressively larger ratios.

Comment: ... the antenna elements are not usually spaced by as much as \$\small \lambda /2\$